# Is there a way to use another computer GPU in vscode notebook?

Tags: python

I have laptop A with Nvidia 2060 and desktop B with Nvidia 3080 in my room.

All settings, files, and notebooks are in laptop A.
Laptop A and Desktop B are on the same network (with a network hub).

Is it possible to run notebooks (that contains tensorflow neural network parts) on desktop B GPU while working from laptop A ?

I have seen people using juypter, docker and else to use Remote GPU, but is there a way to do it from Vscode so other students that are not familiar with this can reproduce it easily ?

Thank you very much

Comment: This is a really good question, I'm curious to see the answers. Maybe there is a better way, but two possible solutions are VS Code Server (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server) and SSH  (code.visualstudio.com/learn/develop-cloud/ssh-lab-machines)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if you get it running but try this:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server